# Why little yellow tint on display?

Tags: 14.04, display, display-manager, display-resolution, color-management

Why little bit yellow tint on Ubuntu OS? When I see white colors on both the windows and Ubuntu. Ubuntu is little yellow display. Why Its little tuned by  Yellow color? Sorry I don't know weather its right place to ask. But I searched somewhere doesn't find answer.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot/photo of the issue?

Comment: Sorry @Wilf I think screenshot wont explain my issue.  If possible just open any website on both windows and Ubuntu. Just watch out the white color on the website. Sure you will come to know the different.

Comment: Do you happen to have f.lux installed?

Comment: @Zacharee1 No its a fresh OS.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

1. Open System Settings and go into Color.
2. From here, click Add Profile.
3. Select the Best RGB profile and click Add.
4. Hopefully, a window will come up asking you to download extra packages. Let it install them.
5. Back inside the Color settings, select your monitor and click Calibrate....

Comment: Alternatively, if the Windows setup has the screen calibrated then COPY the color profile (*.icm or similar) file to the Linux installation and activate it - or vice versa.

Comment: Going thru the steps, my 'Calibrate' is btn is grayed out. I am unable to click on it.

Answer (score 5):

Anyone finding this who is running Ubuntu 18.04. I had the same problem with a dull, yellow hue to my display. This was resolved by navigating to

> Activities -> Search for 'color' -> Select Color settings 'Calibrate the color of your devices...'

Turn the 'Laptop Screen' profile and switch it to the 'Off' position and restart your laptop. For me, on this old *Sony Vaio*, no more yellow things perturb the display.

Comment: Not sure why my wording was 'corrected' into grammatically incorrect English (with 2 approvals, no less). There was nothing wrong with my original wording. 

And 'tinge' is a word by the way:

 (tĭnj)►
v. To apply a trace of color to; tint.

Comment: Thank you! I was really struggling and that worked perfectly!